# Clearsessions command in Django

Tags: django, session-state

Can I run this command on my production server without any risk? Will all sessions be deleted or how is `clearsessions` affecting my database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`clearsessions` will only clean up expired sessions, so it won't impact any active users (eg logging them out).